# Redirect users from HTTPS to HTTP via IIS and the web.config file

Tags: iis

I am attempting to redirect anyone visiting a HTTPS page to a HTTP page however the rule seems to fail and not redirect the user at all i.e. displays an untrusted connection and if I accept the untrusted connection it returns a 404 page. The page I am attempting to redirect to exists.

Is there a way I can redirect a user from HTTPS to HTTP? The rule I have is

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to https">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="443" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: also consider this similar question and answer in SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/43631676/184572

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple things to keep in mind.  The request must first bind to the server before the redirect, so you can't avoid the untrusted connection except to make sure that you have a valid cert bound to the site.  So a redirect won't help with that.

Your redirect url has https:// in it.  Did you mean for it to be http://?  It should target http.

And if you want to allow some pages to not redirect (like your login page), then you can add exclude conditions for {URL}, or do it in the match url="" section.

Comment: Thanks and you are correct that it needs to redirect to HTTP. I have updated my question. I know that the request will need to bind to the server first before redirecting but is there anything I can do before it hits the server to redirect? Can you show me an example of how I can exclude URLs?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey 1) For detecting HTTPS usually {HTTPS} variable is used instead of {SERVER_PORT} (but this, actually, depends on circumstances): `<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />`. This allows to have rule working even if HTTPS is bound to non-standard port (other than 443). 2) This condition will tell IIS to NOT redirect if `/login.php` page is requested: `<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/login\.php$" negate="true" />`. You can add few of such exclusions as separate conditions or merge them into 1 if that is possible.

Comment: @LazyOne - Thanks LazyOne. What is the difference between {SERVER_PORT} and {HTTPS}? Also is there a way to intercept the request before the SSL handshake? The reason I ask is because the requested URL does not have a SSL certificate seeing that the domains have changed and instead need to redirect the user to the appropriate page.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey 1) `{SERVER_PORT}` checks for specific server port while `{HTTPS}` checks if HTTPS on or off regardless of port number. 2) No -- HTTP part of HTTPS kicks in when Secure Channel already established. You cannot intercept it with URL Rewrite as it simply occurs AFTER SSL negotiation.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey, I can only +1 LazyOne's replies.  That's exactly correct.  You can consider wildcard certs, or in IIS7, you can have multiple certs per site. (in IIS6 you can just setup redirect sites with unique bindings).  I haven't tried them yet but http://www.affirmtrust.com/ recently announced free certs.

Comment: @Scott Forsyth - MVP - Thanks although I don't quite follow what you meant by 'in IIS7, you can have multiple certs per site'

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey, in IIS7 there is new support for adding multiple HTTPS bindings, each with their own unique certificate.  This means that you can have a different certificate per domain name, all on the same site. You do need a unique IP address per domain name though if you're using different certs!  So you'll need to use up some public IPs to accomplish this.